# Python 2.7 installed on Debian 10

Tags: debian, python, mx-linux

I recently installed MX-Linux and cannot understand why Python 2.7.16 is installed on Debian 10

I just came across the following information whe googling

> Python 3.0 was released in 2008. Its newest version, 3.6, was released in 2016, and version 3.7 is currently in development. Although Python 2.7 is still widely used, Python 3 adoption is growing quickly. ... Notably, on January 1, 2018, Python 2.7 will “retire” and no longer be maintained.

So the first question is why a fresh release of Debian relies on an old Python version?

Then I may ask - could I just upgrade to a more recent release of Python, for instance 3.7, or may it corrupt the OS somehow?

Comment: Why gets the quesion downvotes, because it is outdated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 2 and Python 3 are significantly different, and most programs written using Python 2 can’t be [migrated automatically to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html). Debian 10 includes both: Python 2.7.16, and Python 3.7.3. These were the versions of Python 2 and 3 current at the time Debian 10 was frozen for release.

Python 2 is no longer supported upstream, since earlier this year (not 2018 as indicated in your quote, which is based on out-dated information), but it is still supported by a number of distributions. It is however being phased out; Debian 11 will still include it, along with a limited number of Python 2 modules, but that’s only to preserve minimal backward compatibility to allow a small number of Python 2 applications to continue working. Any new Python development should use Python 3.

Regarding your last question, you can most definitely install the `python3` packages provided in Debian. Whatever you do though, don’t try installing newer versions of Python 3 manually; there are a large number of questions here arising from users breaking their setup by doing so.

Comment: thanks for answer, but when writing **python --version** in a terminal it outputs **Python 2.7.16** only. Why's that?

Comment: Because `python` is Python 2; for Python 3, run `python3`.